# Problems with custom 3d renderer in java

Tags: java, rendering, renderer, 3d-rendering

So I have recently started on my own 3D renderer in Java. I have made a cube and a camera that can be moved with `WASD` and mouse. I have just one problem:

When the camera looks away or a point of the cube ends up on the corner of the display the renderer freaks out (it renders a polygon that shouldn't be drawn).

After debugging I saw that the renderer wanted to render a point at `x: -142500` (way out of my `1500x1500` window). I then tried to fix this by implementing screen clipping (so that `142500` x coordinate would be moved to the edge of the screen). Well, that didn't work either :(

I would appreciate any help.
[The problem (the red is where the edge is and the blue striped area is where the white triangle should have rendered)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyaO9.png)

Edit: [dropbox jar file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rxc023iexy6ecg9/3d-renderer.jar?dl=0)

Comment: Edit your question and add a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  If you don’t include any code, we can’t provide any suggestions for how to improve it.

Comment: Hi Filip, welcome to StackOverflow. Following from VGR's comment, please include your code as `formatted code blocks` in the question, not external links. If there is so much code that that is not practical, please pare it down to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)